# New HDDs making whirring sound when put into PC

Tags: hard-drive

I have come to replacing my old 1TB HDD (WD Blue, was freezing I/O sometimes) with a new 4TB one, however after trying two new HDDs (specifically [WD Red](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-red-sata-hdd#WD40EFAX) and [WD Red Plus](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-red-plus-sata-3-5-hdd#WD40EFZX)), I am facing strange noise issues. The strange part is that the sounds started being apparent only once the HDD got installed into PC ‒ I cloned my old HDD to it through USB and this sound was not present before or after the operation, only when the new HDD got installed to the PC in place of the old one.

Before installing, the HDD actually made high-pitched chirping sounds on I/O, which is fine I suppose (the old HDD was making quiet high-pitched scraping sounds anyway), but now the sound is low-pitched grinding or whirring, just the cadence is the same and is much more hearable.

[This is the sound](https://is4.site/storage/hdd1.ogg) it is making when fully accessed (running checkdisk).

[image: Spectrogram of the first sound.]

[This is the sound](https://is4.site/storage/hdd2.ogg) it makes when I go over the raw bytes from the beginning to end in FlexHEX.

[image: Spectrogram of the second sound.]

Now the interesting part is that the spectrogram shows two distinct sounds, the low-frequency one below 2 kHz, but also the original chirping high-frequency sound at around 5 kHz. When [isolated](https://is4.site/storage/hdd2-highpass.ogg), the high-pitch sound in the recording is indeed what I was hearing before I put it into the PC. I cannot confirm whether I was hearing this sound in the case of the first HDD I tried (WD Red) since I have returned it already.

Now I am not sure whether this is the sound it is supposed to be making, but it is definitely concerning and annoying, and weird considering two HDDs I have tried already have this issue. I am also not sure where the issue comes from ‒ whether the original chirping of the HDD is causing some sort of resonance in the PC slot leading to the whirring, whether the SATA 3 connection in the PC is making a difference as opposed to the USB connector, whether it could have been caused by the two HDDs getting damaged by the transportation (were both individually wrapped in bubble wrap in envelope, not the safest way), or whether I should have chosen WD Blue instead of WD Red anyway.

This is the reading of the new HDD's sensors:

[image: S.M.A.R.T. sensors reading.]

Comment: New HDDs making whirring sound when put into PC ......... Is it mounted so that it makes noise against the computer frame or other fixed part?

Comment: @John I suppose so, it is mounted and screwed in a (I suppose) standard metal tray for HDDs, and supported by the little metal "hands" that are part of it. The old HDD was mounted in the exactly same position (and I put it back there for a while before getting the 2nd HDD to try and it was fine).

Comment: Does playing with the drive's AAM settings make a difference?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen The drive does not support such setting, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I hope that the Disk Temperature of 113 is in fahrenheit (45 celsius) ... The raw value is 34 and it also doesn't fit.

Comment: @harrymc It is at 37 °C now and definitely was not higher before. Not sure what unit Hard Disk Sentinel uses there, but temperature is not an issue.

Comment: If you want a silent system then replace your hdd with SSD as they are silent.  Otherwise you may need rubber grommets of some description to absorb the vibrations.

Answer (score 1):

> I cloned my old HDD to it through USB and this sound was not present before or after the operation, only when the new HDD got installed to the PC in place of the old one.

Listening to your audio samples I'd say all this is normal for some makes of HDD, the diff from the first to the second is simply the intensity of the work it does.
*(e.g. Old time's Seagate drives)*
All this amplified by it being mounted in a metal box / drive bay.

**What one can do about it?**
Read up on vibration dampening and apply it in any manner you can think of.

In my opinion most of the noise should be possible to reduce;
e.g. by making sure there is no mechanical attachment between the HDD and other large metallic structures (e.g. the PC's box).

One extreme way would be to suspend the HDD in some sort of rubber bands ;-)

Comment: Is it sensible to squish some foam between the hard drive and the metal case?

Comment: Maybe, make sure to not place it in the way for cooling. Metal to metal contact is generally to be avoided.